# Do supervisors take a person as PhD students who abandoned his graduate program?

Tags: publications, phd, computer-science

As a professor, would you take a person as your Ph.D. student who abandoned his graduate CS program 3 years ago (hence incomplete), but has published 2 research papers per year  (total 6) in a peer-reviewed journal?

Why or why not?

Comment: Some universities may have minimum requirements for doing a PhD that would exclude you without a graduate degree. PhD students are in many places picked by the departments or admission commissions rather than the professors themselves. Personally I'd always try to look at the "whole picture" rather than using this as a straight reason for rejection, however in the place where I currently am, it's not my call to make in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

I would consider it, but only after having a talk with the student. In addition to the usual about background and research interests, I'd want to know about why it was abandoned and how we can have some assurance it won't occur again.

But for many this might also depend on how much support the advisor was expected to give. In a situation in which a lot is required (such as a lab), the situation gets more difficult. In other situations, where the professor provides mostly feedback and a few ideas, it is less critical. In CS, it could go either way, depending on the topic of the dissertation research.

But your activity in the interim indicates some seriousness (assuming "a person" means yourself).

Comment: ***I would consider it, but only after having a talk with the student.*** --- https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/139129/100406 ,, https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/140150/100406

Comment: Suppose, a student comes to you with the aforementioned situation and tells you that he is interested in doing a Ph.D. What would you tell him?

Comment: It would depend on the outcome of the conversation. So, maybe yes, maybe not. Maybe I'd suggest someone else. Lots of possibilities.